# Valgrind memcheck keeps dying before it finishes

Tags: valgrind

When running valgrind memcheck, it keeps dying and killing the process with output like the following:

```
valgrind: m_oset.c:156 (elem_of_node): Assertion 'n->magic == OSET_MAGIC' failed.
valgrind: bad magic on node 0x1574B69EE0 = ffffdddd (expected 5b1f)
possible causes:
 - node metadata corrupted by overwriting end of element?
```

I am interpreting this as valgrind stopping because one of its internal data structures appears to be corrupted due to a failed assertion.  I don't understand why this would happen, though.  It seems to be somewhat repeatable in my environment.  The exact node address differs each run, but it is always approximately around the same address (another run showed `0x1573C405E0`).  Is this indicative of bad RAM, some memory corruption bug in my software, a bug in valgrind, or something else?

In case it is helpful, I am running the following:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --gen-suppressions=all --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=yes --vgdb=no [my_application]
```

I've used valgrind memcheck in the past without running into issues like this, and I'm not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Which valgrind version ? On which platform (processor, OS) ? Normally, when using memcheck, before such an assertion failure, you should see some  (application) errors reported by valgrind. First fix these errors then.

Comment: Version 3.13.0.  RedHat 7 on a 16 core Intel server.  There were no errors of consequence printed earlier.  However, I do see another valgrind assert earlier after digging through the ouput: `valgrind: m_oset.c:726 (avl_remove): Assertion 't->root == n' failed.`

Comment: After further digging, it looks like valgrind's crashing issues are tied to adding some of the valgrind macros to my code, namely `VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK` and `VALGRIND_DO_CHANGED_LEAK_CHECK`.  Valgrind only dies right after making one of these calls.

Comment: 3.13 is now more than 3 years old.  I suggest to get the latest official release (3.16.1), and compile it. Building valgrind is very easy/has very little dependencies.  Also, would be nice to have an as small as possible reproducer. E.g. if your problem is linked to the valgrind macros, maybe you will reproduce this with a very small program of a few lines that we can look at.

Comment: At this point I think I can get what I need from valgrind by just spacing out the valgrind macro calls significantly to look at the changes, knowing that it will crash after the second call.  Unfortunately it is not straightforward to change the dev tools I'm working with at the moment, so this will have to do.  If I have a chance to upgrade I will do so and see if it still happens.  My original assumption was that this is a user error or hardware problem, not a valgrind bug, but perhaps it is/was at least for the version I'm using.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Note that you can also do interactive leak search by using gdb+vgdb.  You can then put breakpoints where needed and search for leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the 5th comment from my original question, this appears to be related to the valgrind macros and can at least be worked around by spacing out the macro calls to give more processing time prior to the crash.  Moving to a newer version might help, too, but is unknown and not an option for me at this time.